# What is this tool (looking like half a birds beak on a shaft with a handle) for?

Tags: tool-identification

Found this tool while cleaning out a workshop close to the sea, but **what is it for and what's its name**? I've guessed it's something for knotting, but can't find a reference on how to use it (it might of course be something totally else :)

The handle is in wood, the rest of the tool is made from steel, and the front part (that measures 20 mm at its widest place), looks like half a birds beak, a little bit curved. The tool is 180 mm long all in all.

Front:
[image]

Side:
[image]

Back:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a *bearing scraper*, used for finishing the inside of soft metal bearings, such as [Babbitt bearings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babbitt_(alloy)#Traditional_Babbitt_bearings) which are made by pouring liquid metal directly around the shaft they will support, then disassembled and cleaned up before use. Such bearings are re-poured when they wear down, so this tool might have been from a maintenance shop, not necessarily a factory that originally made machinery having such bearings.

You can see some very similar tools and their use in [this video on Babbitt bearings from Keith Rucker's YouTube channel, starting at 48:00](https://youtu.be/4v2ivoLkxVw?t=2878). The narrow, slightly curved tip allows working on the perpendicularly curved inside surface of the bearing:

[image: Frame from the above video of a scraper being used on half of a Babbitt bearing]

(In this particular picture, it almost looks like the concave side is up, but actually the convex side is up, so the two edges are against the surface to scrape.)

Comment: That's it! Very interesting to finally get to know what it is! I don't have any soft metal bearings so I'll try to give it to someone that has :)

Answer (score 0):

Thinking it is a woodworking tool for carving wood. They come in all different shapes and sizes. The images you provided have a similar body and shape commonly bought in a set.

[image]
Image source from: [here](https://www.etsy.com/listing/224770994/wood-carving-tools-forged-chisel-carving)

Comment: Lyssagal, it doesn't look like there's any cutting edge on the tool in the question.